# Powershell - Comparing AD User Properties in CSV file

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have some of the AD properties of a user at two different times exported to two different CSV files. How can I compare the two files to find which properties have changed? I have looked at `compare-object $file1 $file2|select property1, property2`... but it seems to just indicate that something has changed, but does not indicate which property exactly has changed.

Comment: Need to see the files sample. Cannot help without that. Also would be nice to see what you have tried to we can help finish the solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello. If you consider that the files that are overwritten regularly,
>   and it happens that some attributes change, then you can try the
>   following (maybe it help for you):

```
$date1_stfile=(Get-Item  D:\1.txt).LastWriteTime  
$date2_ndfile=(Get-Item  D:\2.txt).LastWriteTime 

if ($date1_stfile -ge $date2_ndfile) {

$c=get-content D:\1.txt  
$d=Get-Content D:\2.txt

$compare1=Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $d -DifferenceObject $c | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } | select InputObject
$compare1
if ($compare1 -ne $null) {
Write-Host "changed in file 1"
}
else {Write-Host "no changed discover"}
}

if ($date1_stfile -le $date2_ndfile) {

$e=get-content D:\1.txt 
$f=Get-Content D:\2.txt

$compare2=Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $e -DifferenceObject $f | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } | select InputObject
$compare2 
if ($compare2 -ne $null) {
Write-Host "changed in file 2"
}
else {Write-Host "no changed discover"}
}
```

> Also you can try this:

```
$date1_stfile=(Get-Item  D:\1.txt).LastWriteTime  
$date2_ndfile=(Get-Item  D:\2.txt).LastWriteTime

$c=get-content D:\1.txt  
$d=Get-Content D:\2.txt


if ($date1_stfile -le $date2_ndfile) {

$d | % {

if ($c -notcontains $_) {

$_ + " In the file 2"

}

}
}
if ($date1_stfile -ge $date2_ndfile) {
$c | % {

if ($d -notcontains $_) {

$_ + " In the file 1"

}
}
}
```